# How do I install Perl Modules on Scripting Layer for Android (SL4A)?

Tags: perl, module, sl4a

I just installed [SL4A](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/) to test Perl on my Motorola Milestone. Is there a way to install a module? I need LWP::Simple.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can install modules locally with normal CPAN clients and then push the perl modules to your Android device's SL4A site_perl with adb. [cpanm](http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/App-cpanminus-1.4004/) has --local-lib option, which makes it easy to locally install modules.

```
% adb -e push /path/to/library/HTTP /sdcard/com.googlecode.perlforandroid/extras/perl/site_perl/HTTP
```

Note that this should only work with pure perl modules. I am not sure how you can build binary that is compatible to your SL4A environment.